# How to restore sybase (SAP ASE) .db and .log backup on a another system?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

How can I restore (or read in a some decent form) a sybase backup that I've been given to be analyzed?

I have been given a backup from sybase database that contains a single .db and one .log file.

I'm new to sybase and I have no access to original system nor I have any information about the database structure that these files contain.

The thing I know is that backup is probably made with command

```
dbbackup -c "userid=xxx;password=xxx" -d -t -y D:\path\to\backup
```

I've been asked to analyze the content of the database and to do that I've set up a SAP ASE 16.0 on RedHat 7.

I have tried to restore the backup using the load database command but all I get is a error report:

```
Backup Server session id is: 17. Use this value when executing the
'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change
request from the Backup Server.
Backup Server: 4.10.2.1: Label validation error: first label not VOL1.
Backup Server: 6.31.2.4: Volume rejected.
Backup Server: 1.14.2.2: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD
session must exit.
Backup Server: 6.32.2.3: /data/sybase/backup/adbname.db: volume not valid
or not requested (server: , session id: 17.)
Backup Server: 1.14.2.4: Unrecoverable I/O or volume error.  This DUMP or LOAD
session must exit.
Msg 8009, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'ASE1', Line 1:
Error encountered by Backup Server.  Please refer to Backup Server messages for
details.
```

Answer (score 0):

the error indicates that the database backup file is not valid.
Are you sure that it is a Sybase ASE dump file. ".db" files look like more DB2 backup files than ASE backup files?

Comment: A very valid question. After getting  more information about the files I was provided it turns out I have database files from Sybase SQL Anywhere 8. So this was infact a common communication issue between people. I still cant open the files but the issue is not infact Sybase ASE related. Or is there a way to transfer SQL Anywhere database to ASE?

Comment: I don't know much about SQL Anywhere but I feel you better find a way to load your backup to SQL Anywhere first then transfer to another db. To do so, you might need to have a SAP Sxxx account to take a look at http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/sql-anywhere

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't write the restore command for restoring dB and I think you used wrong command for getting backup.
Briefly, for getting backup of a Sybase db you have to write:

create backup

go

Backup files are stored in da\server\instance\dasd\backup\unique_backup_id .

And for load it you have to write:

restore backup "unique_backup_id"

go

If restore backup succeeds, the server automatically shuts down; you must manually restart it.

Resources is: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1570/html/commands/X16531.htm